# Database project - deploy everything without files checked out by others

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have database project stored in TFS and the issue is that when two people works on the same database they overwrite changes to each other's when they deploy their not checked in versions. For example:

```
Initial code:
code1: xxxxx
code2: xxxxx

code1: xxxxx  \_ developer 1
code2: yyyyy  /

code1: zzzzz  \_ developer 2
code2: xxxxx  /
```

When developer 1 deploys code 1 he overwrites changes deployed by developer 2.

Solution for that would be a configuration which creates deployment script without files that are checked out by others.

Comment: A better long term solution would be to do all of your database development locally. Even if you find a reasonable answer to your question you'll still run into conflicts when 2 people work on the same file or change the same data.

Comment: In addition to Keith's comment, I'd also consider having a mainline branch into which everyone commits/merges their code for release. Only release from that branch. Everyone can still develop in their own branches, but changes have to be merged into that "release" branch before they will be pushed. If the change isn't there, it won't be released. Still conflicts, but handled in merge and requires some discussion to merge properly.